# Proper use of PHP: header('Content-language: ...');

Tags: php, header, multilingual

aside the obvious fashion of setting the language of a page:

```
<meta name="language" content="de"><html lang="de">
```

I recently found an amazing aspect typical to only the programming language of PHP that could enables developers to set the language at the very top of PHP files:

```
<?php  

 /* Set and pre-define the language in the header;
  * Eliminating guesswork for the Header language.
  */

  header('Content-language: de');

?>
```

Two questions arise eveidentaly to the PHP programmer:

**Main Question: When should one set the language in a PHP header?**

SideQ1: Big websites don't bother using it: why don't they?

SideQ2: Do search engines listen to this and if so, what implications does this PHP header have?

Comment: This is not isolated to only the PHP language. The PHP header() function is used to set a raw HTTP Header, which many languages can do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Shorter answer**:  Don't bother, cause browsers typically ignore it.

**Longer answer**:  The W3C recommends using the `lang` attribute in HTML over the `Content-Language` header in HTTP:

http://www.w3.org/International/geo/html-tech/tech-lang.html#ri20040808.110827800

Rationale:  User agents tend to ignore the header or implement it inconsistently.

Plus, the `lang` attribute is more flexible.  If you have some content in one language and other in another, you can specify that precisely, like so:

```
<body> 
 <div lang="en" xml:lang="en">
  <h1>Welcome!</h1> 
  <p>Lots of text in English...</p>
 </div>
 <div lang="fr" xml:lang="fr">
  <h1>Bienvenue !</h1> 
  <p>Beaucoup de texte en français...</p>
 </div>
</body>
```

Taken from:  http://www.w3.org/International/geo/html-tech/tech-lang.html#ri20040728.121403792

I don't know about search engines.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this header for informational purposes. But it's primarily meant for [content negotiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation).

Each http URL can transparently refer to different resources. Depending on a clients Accept: and Accept-Language: header, the server can send a specific variant of a resource. And that's when it is advisable that such descriptive headers are included.

If it's used in that fashion, it will be accompanied by a `Vary: *` or `Vary: Accept-Language` header. Otherwise it's really just informational. (It never catched on to be widely used all by itself.)