# Which http headers should I set for multi language site?

Tags: php, html, http, http-headers, multilingual

I'm currently working on a multilanguage site and this is my situation:

- I'm redirecting users to language specific pages: e.g. http://www.example.com/en/ or http://www.example.com/nl/
- On every page I use the `html-lang` tag: `<html lang="<?php echo $lang; ?>">`
- And on every pagina I use the `hreflang` tags.

According to answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325784/http-status-code-for-language-redirect) and [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/26953/redirect-from-the-main-page-on-multilanguage-site) article I need to set a http-header too, but I can't figure out how to do this and what kind of header I should set. Is it the `Accept-Language` or the `Content-Language`? And is it really a must to set a http-header for multi-language websites? And is Accept-Language a request and not a response?

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: So why are they talking in the answers about setting the HTTP headers? And how to do it the right way?

Comment: Because the `Accept-Language` _request_ header indicates the language settings and preferences of the user agent, and might be used to redirect to, or serve, a document in a specific language.

Comment: Yes I understand, but they are talking about '**responding** with a Vary header', so that I have to do something.

Comment: It's still not clear for me if I have to use the Vary header or not (see comments under your answer too).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And is it really a must to set a http-header for multi-language websites?

From [HTTP headers, meta elements and language information - W3.org](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-http-and-lang):

> When specifying the language for text-processing you are declaring the language in which a specific range of text is actually written, so that user agents or applications that manipulate the text (such as voice browsers, spell checkers, or style processors) can effectively handle the text in question.

So yes, it makes sense from a usability standpoint to declare the language used on a page, and the language of the intended audience of a page.

For how to specify this, see the same page:

> The HTTP Content-Language header can be used to provide metadata about the intended audience of the page, and can indicate that this is more than one language. The Content-Language value for an http-equiv attribute on a meta element should no longer be used. You should use a language attribute on the html tag to declare the default language of the actual text in the page.

And [HTML meta tag for content language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417923/html-meta-tag-for-content-language):

> should really be expressed in the headers. For example:
>
> ```
> Content-language: es
> ```

The `Accept-Language` is not a response header but a request header, so with both `Content-language` as response header and the `<html lang="">` attribute in the HTML element you're good to go.

As for the `Vary: X, Y` response header: this means that the response to the *current request URI* will differ when headers X or Y differ.

This is for example important when doing a redirect. Say on your landing page, you determine where to redirect based on the `Accept-Language` request header:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Accept-Language: en
```

Your site will then redirect to the English subsite:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://example.com/en
Vary: Accept-Language
```

This will tell the user agent (browsers, search engines) that requesting the same URI with a different `Accept-Language` will yield a different result. For example:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Accept-Language: es
```

Your site will then redirect to the Spanish subsite:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://example.com/es
Vary: Accept-Language
```

Comment: Thank you! So I don't have to set a Vary header (related to language) at all in my multi language site?

Comment: You use the Vary header if the response ... varies per request header. You'd use that when the URI remains the same, but the resulting response differs by looking at the Accept-Language request header (and so also when basing the redirect on that).

Comment: Thanks, so I need to set it when the URL is always the same (so that http://www.example.com displays different content for Spanish and French users). And also when I redirect users to http://www.example.com/es/ or another url depending on their language (that is my case)?

Comment: The vary header tells the user agent: you're going to get a different response when the specified headers change. `Vary: Accept-Language` will tell the user agent that requesting with a different language will yield a different result on the same URI.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but I don't need it when the url for every language is different? (http://www.example.com/en/ and http://www.example.com/es/)

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! It's just so strange that there isn't any multi-language website (and I tested it with +-50 websites) that sends a `Vary: Accept-Language` response (like Facebook, Microsoft, Apple, Airbnb, ...)

Comment: Content-Language is not really necessary: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423989/proper-use-of-php-headercontent-language

Comment: @Jordy indeed not necessary, but it is informational. Browsers may ignore it, but other systems may utilize it.